# How to see object code generated by g++?

Tags: programming, vim, c++, g++

```
g++ -c xyz.cpp
```

creates an object file `xyz.o`

But when I open it in vim editor it shows some crazy text...

How can I see the machine code?

What package can use to open and see that machine code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `binutils` package.

In it you'll find objdump - display information from object files.

Then try running `objdump -d xyz.o`.

Comment: It works GREAT !!!

Answer (score 2):

Machine code generated by your compiler is not supposed to be human readable, but rather completely optimized to run as fast as possible on your processor.

However, you *can* read symbols from the binary files like this:

```
$ nm main.o | c++filt         
                 U _Unwind_Resume                                                                                                    
                 U FactoryImpl::FactoryImpl()                                                                                        
                 U UI::UI(Subject*)                                                                                                  
                 U operator delete(void*)                                                                                            
                 U operator new(unsigned long)                                                                                       
                 U __gxx_personality_v0                                                                                              
0000000000000000 T main
```

Notes:

- `nm` and `c++filt` are from the `binutils` package you probably have already when developing.
- you can only view the symbols if they're not removed by compiler options.

*I just realized my answer wasn't really answering your question about reading the actual machine code. However, I think it provides some useful information instead. For reading the assembly-level operations for your processor, use `objdump -d` as proposed by @hnasarat*

Comment: But how to read symbols ? It shows somwthing like this: ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^[^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^

Comment: @SAM What exactly don't you understand about the example in my answer? It shows symbols from my ``main.o`` file with the given command. Try to run the same on your ``.o`` file.

Comment: @SAM I missed some essential part of your question. See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `-S` flag to make the compiler output assembly code.

So for your example the code would be `g++ -S xyz.cpp` and the assembly would be printed in `xyz.s`.

Comment: If you also select the lowest optimisation level -O0 you may find the object code more understandable because less optimisation transformations have been applied to the intermediate code.

Comment: `-O0` is (usually) the default optimization level so i felt safe in leaving it out.